# I need help for Function "press" in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

1.I extract to widget and write final Function press then i write onTap: press and i have mistake. How to solve this problem?
2.

```
class CharactersCards extends StatelessWidget {
  const CharactersCards({
    Key? key,
    required this.image,
    required this.title,
    required this.element,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

final String image, title, element;
final Function press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        left:  kDefaultPadding,
        top:  kDefaultPadding / 2,
        bottom: kDefaultPadding * 2.5,
      ),
      width: size.width * 0.4,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget> [
          Image.asset(image),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: press,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding / 2),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),

                ),
```

I wrote press: () {},

Comment: As you wrote hope it is working, Can you describe the issue a little more?

Answer (score 1):

option 1:

you can directly write your functionality inside ontap function like below

```
onTap: () {
//here you can write your functionality
},
```

option 2 :

you can wrote a simple function and call it inside ontap property like below

```
onTap: () {
yourFunctionName(),
}

void yourFunctionName() {
//write your functionality here
};
```

added option 3 :
you can use it like function call back.. you can create a class and make a field like below and can write your functionality

```
class DrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerListTile({
    Key? key,
    // For selecting those three line once press "Command+D"
    required this.title,
    required this.svgSrc,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title, svgSrc;
  final VoidCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: press,
      horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
      leading: SvgPicture.asset(
        svgSrc,
        color: Colors.black87,
        height: 16,
      ),
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
DrawerListTile(
            title: "Invite",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/user-list.svg",
            press: () {
              //your functionality here
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Also this is possible: () => press()

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your problem correcly, wrap your `Container` with `InkWell` or `GestureDetector` on call you `press` inside `onTap`.

```
GestureDetector(
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        left:  kDefaultPadding,
        top:  kDefaultPadding / 2,
        bottom: kDefaultPadding * 2.5,
      ),
      width: size.width * 0.4,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget> [
          Image.asset(image),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: press,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding / 2),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),

                ),

    onTap:press
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this

```
final Function() press;
```

or use VoidCallback instead of Function() while declaring like this:

```
final VoidCallback press;
```